# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":

Tags: ruby, jtable, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When i am starting the server i have got the error like this

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jtable-rails (= 0.1.3) ruby depends on
      rails (= 3.0.5) ruby

    rails (3.2.9)
```

How can i solvve this problem? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jTable-Rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jtable-rails) has a dependency on Rails with the version specified to `rails ~> 3.0.0`. This syntax means that any the Rails version has to be `>= 3.0.0` and `< 3.1.0`.

This way, you won't get the gem to work with Rails 3.2 the way it is. Chances are though that the assets in the gem (the javascript files you are trying to include) are outdated anyways if the gem has not been updated for one and a half years.

You can just download the jTable assets and place them in your `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets` directories. Then just require them as usual with `//= require jtable` in the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee` and in your main stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

look up this gem version from http://rubygems.org/gems/jtable-rails/versions/0.2.5, you should upgrade your jtable-rails version to latest which compatible to rails 3.2.9

Comment: add gem "jtable-rails", "~> 0.2.5" in your Gemfile